# OpenShift routes with path results in ignoring sub routes

Tags: rest, openshift, openshift-origin

I'm currently using OpenShift for the depoloyment of a node.js-Application. This application exposes a REST api.

As long as i don't use a path in Openshift and the route is something like

**www.app.host.com**

the API works fine. Now I want to host multiple apps on one host, as i don't want to have to make a certificate signing request everytime I add a new one. But when I use a path in OpenShift routes like

**www.host.com/app/**

all the trafic will be sent to the apps root route. So

**www.host.com/app/request/something**

will still result the traffic ending up on the welcome page. Do you have any ideas how to get OpenShift to still accept the subroutes?

Comment: Can you show the ``Route`` definition for that with the path set? IOW, output of ``oc get route nameofroute -o json``.

Comment: Note that path based routes are not allowed in OpenShift Online Starter as you can't override the hostname which would allow you to use same hostname in different routes. For OpenShift Online Pro or your own OpenShift cluster the feature should work.

Comment: NAME: route.name
HOST/PORT: host.subdom.dom.net
PATH: /path    
SERVICES: services.name
PORT: 8080-tcp
TERMINATION:
WILDCARD: None

Comment: Are you sure the "other" app is expecting the full path? As in, it should handle ``www.host.com/app/`` not just ``www.host.com``. Anyway ``oc describe routes`` should give you hints about problems with conflicting or invalid routes. Look for "Requested Host..."

Comment: www.host.com/app gets handled as it should. The funny thing is just that  no matter what I send after that (even if it's a post or get request gets ignored)
It will always treat every request (www.host.com/app/something/from/api) as a get request to www.host.com/app the root of my node.js app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's what you'll have to do. You have to include your path into the node.js application.

So if you're using /yourapp/ (be sure to include the slash at the end) you'll have to change your routes from

**/api/dosomething** to **/yourapp/api/dosomething**

In my case I used an environment varible as I didn't want to hardcode the path into my app. so now it basically looks like this

```
var requestPath = (process.env.ROUTE_PATH || '') + '/request';
var authPath = (process.env.ROUTE_PATH || '') + '/auth';

app.use(requestPath, routesRequest);
app.use(authPath, routesAuth);
```

After that, just set your ROUTE_PATH environment variable in the deployment to **/yourapp** and you're good to go